# How to add an icon to app_name for an APK

Tags: android, apk

How i can add an icon for app_name also how to  change font and color for the strings in the strings.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MDF Service</string>
    <string name="service_ticker">MDF running</string>
    <string name="service_title">By Amrka</string>
    <string name="service_text">MDF is running.</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: You mean set the app's icon? As for changing font and colour of a text are completely different subjects

Comment: You have to add the icon in the manifest of the application under then tag : 
"android:icon" . give it to a reference from drawable.

Comment: @hamzakhan
can u please write exactly how it looks , i already have the png icon in the drawable but dont know how to refer it in the strings.xml

Answer (score -1):

To set the app icon you must set the `android:icon` attribute in the `application` tag in your manifest, as mentioned in the comments. Whatever image you pass as a value will be your app icon and will appear along with your `app_name` string in your device's app list.

It's a terrible practice to reference anything other than strings in the strings file because, as the name suggests, it's for strings only.

Image files are placed either in drawable or mipmap, usually drawable to keep it simple.

Comment: i already have this in my android manifest 

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:persistent="true">

and i have icon for the apk itself but i want to add thi small icon that appears in notification menu beside the app name